# Unable to compile Android hello world on Netbeans

Tags: android, netbeans

This is my very first post on this extremely helpful site!

After 30 minutes of Googling and discovering the very helpful automated search function as you type your question's name, I figured it's time I finally made an account and ask!

Alright, this is the first time I'm getting my hands dirty, and I saw hit with an error straight in my face, in the form of:

I understand some coding concepts, however I'm still extremely new and I'd like to learn what's causing this to happen from the helpful people on this site, thanks!

```
clean:
Deleting directory C:\Users\User\Documents\NetBeansProjects\AndroidApplication1\bin
Deleting directory C:\Users\User\Documents\NetBeansProjects\AndroidApplication1\gen
Creating output directories if needed...
Created dir: C:\Users\User\Documents\NetBeansProjects\AndroidApplication1\bin
Created dir: C:\Users\User\Documents\NetBeansProjects\AndroidApplication1\bin\res
Gathering info for AndroidApplication1...
Android SDK Tools Revision 19
Project Target: Google APIs
Vendor: Google Inc.
Platform Version: 2.3.3
API level: 10
------------------
Resolving library dependencies:
No library dependencies.

------------------
API<=15: Adding annotations.jar to the classpath.

------------------
WARNING: No minSdkVersion value set. Application will install on all Android versions.
Created dir: C:\Users\User\Documents\NetBeansProjects\AndroidApplication1\gen
Created dir: C:\Users\User\Documents\NetBeansProjects\AndroidApplication1\bin\classes
----------
Handling aidl files...
No AIDL files to compile.
----------
Handling RenderScript files...
No RenderScript files to compile.
----------
Handling Resources...
Generating resource IDs...
----------
Handling BuildConfig class...
Generating BuildConfig class.
Compiling 3 source files to C:\Users\User\Documents\NetBeansProjects\AndroidApplication1\bin\classes
Converting compiled files and external libraries into C:\Users\User\Documents\NetBeansProjects\AndroidApplication1\bin\classes.dex...
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
Error occurred during initialization of VM
Could not reserve enough space for object heap
C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk\tools\ant\build.xml:818: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk\tools\ant\build.xml:820: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk\tools\ant\build.xml:832: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk\tools\ant\build.xml:278: null returned: 1
BUILD FAILED (total time: 3 seconds)
```

And the lines where the error happened on:

C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk\tools\ant\build.xml

```
<!-- Converts this project's .class files into .dex files -->
    <target name="-dex" depends="-compile, -post-compile, -obfuscate">
818     <do-only-if-manifest-hasCode elseText="hasCode = false. Skipping...">
            <!-- only convert to dalvik bytecode is *not* a library -->
820         <do-only-if-not-library elseText="Library project: do not convert bytecode..." >
                <!-- special case for instrumented builds: need to use no-locals and need
                     to pass in the emma jar. -->
                <if condition="${build.is.instrumented}">
                    <then>
                        <dex-helper nolocals="true">
                            <external-libs>
                                <fileset file="${emma.dir}/emma_device.jar" />
                            </external-libs>
                        </dex-helper>
                    </then>
                    <else>
832                     <dex-helper />
                    </else>
                </if>
            </do-only-if-not-library>
        </do-only-if-manifest-hasCode>
    </target>

<!-- Configurable macro, which allows to pass as parameters output directory,
         output dex filename and external libraries to dex (optional) -->
    <macrodef name="dex-helper">
        <element name="external-libs" optional="yes" />
        <attribute name="nolocals" default="false" />
        <sequential>
            <!-- sets the primary input for dex. If a pre-dex task sets it to
                 something else this has no effect -->
            <property name="out.dex.input.absolute.dir" value="${out.classes.absolute.dir}" />

            <!-- set the secondary dx input: the project (and library) jar files
                 If a pre-dex task sets it to something else this has no effect -->
            <if>
                <condition>
                    <isreference refid="out.dex.jar.input.ref" />
                </condition>
                <else>
                    <path id="out.dex.jar.input.ref">
                        <path refid="project.libraries.jars" />
                    </path>
                </else>
            </if>

            <dex executable="${dx}"
                    output="${intermediate.dex.file}"
                    nolocals="@{nolocals}"
278                 verbose="${verbose}">
                <path path="${out.dex.input.absolute.dir}"/>
                <path refid="out.dex.jar.input.ref" />
                <external-libs />
            </dex>
        </sequential>
    </macrodef>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like a memory issue?

> Error occurred during initialization of VM
>      **Could not reserve enough space for object heap**

(emph mine)

Comment: Thanks for the rapid response! I'm running Windows 7, and in the task manager it states that roughly 12% of the CPU is used, and 1.18GB/2GB of the RAM is used, does compiling a simple hello world really takes that much memory?

Comment: I'm not really sure what the normal build stuff is as I use the default Eclipse/SDK combo, but that's what it looks like. It's starting the java vm that's the problem btw as you can also see here: `Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.`

Comment: If that's the case, is there anyway to limit the script to only use a certain amount of memory?

Answer (score 1):

Well I had the exact same errors when I tried to run sample vs-android (https://code.google.com/p/vs-android/) applications.

After a lot of mucking around I don't actually know what causes it but I definitely found a work around to it.

Apparently for some reason, the JVM fails to initialize because its feels there is not enough memory in the system. The way around is to set the JVM to initialize with 512MB of heap size instead of 1024MB default size. In order to do that, do the following :

```
Go to Start->Control Panel->System->Advanced->Environment Variables->System Variables->New:

Variable name: _JAVA_OPTIONS <br>
Variable value: -Xmx512M
```

That solved the error for me though I still have problem deploying to my device but that's a different issue at least it compiled and created an apk - which I could just copy onto the device and run it.